# pojo testing with java 11

Tags: unit-testing, junit, java-11

I am trying to migrate our application from java-8 to java-11. I am facing issue with pojo junit testing. This is working with java-8 , but with java-11, pojo test class is not running.  It looks below dependency is not supporting for java 11.

I have below dependency in dependencies.gradle

```
 testImplementation("pl.pojo:pojo-tester:0.7.6")
```

Below is my PojoTest class

```
package com.product.model;

import static pl.pojo.tester.api.assertion.Assertions.assertPojoMethodsFor;
import org.junit.Test;
import pl.pojo.tester.api.assertion.Method;
import com.product.CassOne;
import com.product.CassTwo;
import com.product.CassThree;

public class PojoTests {
    
    @Test
    public void testPojos() {
        final Class<?>[] classesUnderTest = {
                CassOne.class,
                ClassTwo.class,
                ClassThree.class};

        for (Class<?> classUnderTest : classesUnderTest) {
            assertPojoMethodsFor(classUnderTest).testing(Method.GETTER, Method.SETTER, Method.TO_STRING).areWellImplemented();
        }
    }

}
```

I am facing below Error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at the line 

assertPojoMethodsFor(classUnderTest).testing(Method.GETTER, Method.SETTER, Method.TO_STRING).areWellImplemented();
```

Any suggestion how I can resolve this or any other suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: hey just curious, why you test pojo and whats target test ?

Comment: that library seem no more supported or updated, I would suggest to ignore pojo testing

Comment: I dont know why this was implemented testing pojo. i am guessing testing pojo to ensure its implemented properly and may be for code coverage..

Comment: you can look into ways to ignore pojo from code coverage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have found alternate depedency which supports for java 11

testImplementation("com.obsidiandynamics.pojotester:pojotester:0.9.0")

Comment: Maven repository : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.obsidiandynamics.pojotester/pojotester/0.9.0

Answer (score 1):

You should check which version of apache-commons-lang3 you are using. Changing to versions 3.10 and up fixed the pojo issue for me.